# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi' how can I fix it

Tags: python, gstreamer

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GLib


Gst.init()

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
thread = Thread(target=main_loop.run)
thread.start()

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("ksvideosrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
main_loop_thread.join()
```

**My output error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-ab92d040e545> in <module>
      1 from threading import Thread
      2 from time import sleep
----> 3 import gi
      4 
      5 gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0") ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

**please tell me how I can fix it.**

Comment: pip install gi, run the command to install gi

Comment: Install gi using `pip install pgi`

Answer (score 2):

not sure which OS you're on but if on linux ensure you have deps installed for building [gtk](https://www.gtk.org/) ,

```
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev libxt-dev libgirepository1.0-dev
pip3 install PyGObject pycairo
```

Comment: fixed it for me enabling me to run the throttled terminal app, thanks. (adding this comment to help aid future people googling.)